# Too slow switching for android in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sprite, switching

My game has 1000+ frames and format of sprites is Crunch because of too many sprites in this project.

when I want to switch it from windows to android it takes me almost 1 day to switch (actually I don't permit it to switch completely) but switching to windows is not that much, maybe just 15 minuets.

Just I want to know is it sensible or not ? and if it doesn't, is there any solution ?

Comment: They really need to put a warning, and say this will take a LONG LONG time, are you sure? Perhaps you wish to export a package and do it from a fresh project which will be quicker? ETC. Im sitting now for 19 hrs waiting, from one mouse click!

Answer (score 1):

I have my projects in a version control system (like SVN or Git) and have a checkout per build platform.

In your case you would check them out into two folders:

- YourGame_Windows
- YourGame_Android

Your synchronize both folders by commiting and updating with your version control system.

Comment: I used something near this solution but for a first time, It takes me too much time for importing sprites. I want to know is it normal ?

Comment: yes it is normal. compressing textures takes a lot of time, because they are compressed in expensive ways so that the GPU can read it very fast without decompressing it fully.

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions. Here I will point only 4 of them

1. (IMHO the best option) [Fast Platform Switch plugin](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/fast-platform-switch-one-button-no-nonsense-ultimate-time-saver.200652/)
2. Writing your own importing assets scripts (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html).
3. You can boost speed of importing with switching off compresion of textures/images (Compress Assets on Import in Preferences):

[image]

4. You can boost speed by making sprite packer be enabled only when you make build, or disbale it:

[image]

Comment: Actually for a first point I have a solution so I don't need to use that plugin, and my main question is about first time switching so it doesn't help me anymore.I don't understand second point if it is possible give me more information about it.The forth one is just for sprite sheet so it doesn't related to my question.

Comment: The third one is good for switching but when I want to build the game It starts to compress the sprites so nothing change.