# Unity Android platform iOS switching is very slow

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a project in unity which is switched on android platform. After making some changes in android i have to often convert my project into iOS for iOS build. But the conversion process takes so much time.it takes More than one  and half hour with a dozens of **try again button** clicks . During conversion I came to know  that my CPU utilized 100% and the **PVRTExTool**.exe taking 99% CPU usage.

What I am missing, is this **usual time of conversion**? My project mostly consist of panoramic textures and the conversion time is so long. How can i make it fast? and what will be the impact if i fast it somehow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35089048/1032658

Answer (score 0):

You can have both project versions on your PC at once.
So you can duplicate your project folder, convert it to iOS and leave another 
 folder for Android.

But you will need to synchronize changes between projects using some version control tools.

I'm using GIT for example. Just make sure you have .gitignore for your project, to exclude Library, Temp, Obj, Build folders. Probably somewhere in internet there is example .gitignore file.

Workflow would be:

You work on iOS project, make some changes. Commit/Push changes to repository (could be local).
ANd with your Android project version you just pull changes.

If you haven't used git before, better read some instructions and make backup of your project.